# Axios: Access URL with serialised query string

Tags: axios

Is there a way to access the full URL Axios makes a request to with the query
string params?

I am making a request with:

```js
async function makeRequest(url: string, query: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<unknown> {
  const params = querystring.stringify(query);
  const response = await axios.request({
    method: 'get',
    url,
    params,
  });
  return response.data;
}
```

Given the value for `query` `{ foo: 'bar', baz: 'bat' }` and `url` of `https://api.example.org`, how can I access the full URL `https://api.example.org?foo=bar&baz=bat`?

There *should* be a `request?` property on the `AxiosResponse` object, which I was hoping would hold a reference to the URL, however this is always `undefined` in my testing.

Comment: You could do `url + '?' + Object.entries(query).map(v => v.join('=')).join('&')` if I understand correctly. But keep in mind this won't percent encode values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't need to know how to construct a URL for myself. I want to retrieve the URL that Axios constructs so that I can debug it. The above is just a minimal example. The actual URL I am constructing is more complex.